# Connect to Azure Blob Storage REST API with axios, Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, axios, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to connect to the Azure blob storage API with Node.js. I specifically do not want to use the Blob storage SDK, I want to use axios to hit the REST API. I am just trying to do a simple list containers call as specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2. However, I am getting authorization issues.

Here is my simple axios call:

```
try {
  const azureRes = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url:
      'https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list',
    headers: {
      'x-ms-version': '2017-11-09',
      Authorization:
        'Bearer <access_token>'
    }
  });
  console.log('azureRes', azureRes);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('err:', err);
}
```

However I am getting a response with a 403 status code and the error message:

`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.`

I am authenticating according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory, and I am getting my access token from the Azure storage account Access keys tab. Why is my authentication failing?

Comment: Could you please provide the details of how you get access token?

Comment: From the Azure storage account 'Access keys' tab under 'Key'

Comment: Hi. It is access key and not AD access token. If you want to access storage via AD auth, please refer to my solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access Azure blob REST API with Azure AD auth, please refer to the following steps

1. Assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to AD user or service principal. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az_role_assignment_create) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)

```
az role assignment create \
    --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" \
    --assignee " supported format: object id, user sign-in name, or service principal name." \
    --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>"
```

2. Get Azure AD token

If you use Service principal, we can get access token with the following API. But please note that if you call the rest API in react application, you will get cors error and we cannot enable cors on Azure AD. So I suggest you call the rest API in back-end application

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1          
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=
&scope=http//storage.azure.com/.default
&client_secret=
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

If you use Azure AD user, you can integrate Azure AD auth in your react application with package `react-aad-msal`. Regarding how to configure it, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad/tree/master/samples)

3. Call the API

```
try {
  const azureRes = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url:
      'https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list',
    headers: {
      'x-ms-version': '2017-11-09',
      Authorization:
        'Bearer <access_token>'
    }
  });
  console.log('azureRes', azureRes);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('err:', err);
}
```

---

**Update**
Regarding how to create sas token, please refer to the following code

1. install pcakge `crypto-js`

```
npm install crypto-js
```

2. code

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
const accountName =<>;
  const key=<>;
  const start = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (15 * 60 * 1000));
  const end = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
const signedpermissions = 'rwdlac';
  const signedservice = 'b';
  const signedresourcetype = 'sco';
  const signedexpiry = end.toISOString().substring(0, end.toISOString().lastIndexOf('.')) + 'Z';
  const signedProtocol = 'https';
  const signedversion = '2018-03-28';

  const StringToSign =
      accountName+ '\n' +
      signedpermissions + '\n' +
      signedservice + '\n' +
      signedresourcetype + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedexpiry + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedProtocol + '\n' +
signedversion + '\n';

 var str =CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(StringToSign,CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key));
 var sig = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(str);
 
 
  const sasToken =`sv=${(signedversion)}&ss=${(signedservice)}&srt=${(signedresourcetype)}&sp=${(signedpermissions)}&se=${encodeURIComponent(signedexpiry)}&spr=${(signedProtocol)}&sig=${encodeURIComponent(sig)}`;

const blobUrl= `<you blob URL>?{sasToken }`
```

Comment: With the Javascript SDK I only have to provide the connection string associated with my storage account to authenticate. There must be a simpler way to authenticate with the REST API.

Comment: @rbuzby At the moment, we just can use  Shared Key Shared access signature or Azure Active Directory token to access Azure Blob rest API and cannot use access key to do that directly : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage.  Besides, according to your need, I think you can use Shared access signature to implement it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-performance-checklist#sas-and-cors

Comment: @rbuzby Regarding how to create sas, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas.